# Jquery not woking in masterpage across folder structure

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use an existing dropdown menu built on jquery. I have a folder structure that is necessary for setting up authentication. Also  a masterpage which is at the root required from one or more of the folder directories: Similar to this:

```
Project
    Scripts_Folder
        Jquery.js
        Jcustom.js
    Authenticated_Stuff_Folder
        A_Page.aspx
        A_Nother_Page.aspx
About.aspx
site.master
```

Ive tried setting up the jquery on the site.master like so (after head)

```
<script src="Scripts_Folder /jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts_Folder /jcustom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But when I click on the menu structure container pointing  to A_Page.aspx it says JQuery not defined
So I changed to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts_Folder /jquery.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts_Folder /jcustom.js") %>"></script>
```

Now it works…but only once. If I click on the A_Page,aspx container, it will go to the page fine. If I now click on the container for A_Nother_Page.aspx it will display the Htpp 404 and the path way will show: localhost:port/Project/ Authenticated_Stuff_Folder /Authenticated_Stuff_Folder / A_Nother_Page.aspx (the directory path is there TWICE..

Anyone any ideas?

Still haven't made any headway with this.. I also tried it with another 3rd party dropdown and it had the exact same issue. Surely this is a problem that has been solved somewhere? as its hard to completely avoid directory's in a website. Again anyone can recreate this problem very easily. Create a new ASP Website (I used visual studio 2010) and a folder to the root of the project, create a new aspx page within it. Download one of the open source dropdowns (I tried Superfish and UvumiTools) and incorporate it. Point one of the elements in the menu  to your page that is in the folder you created.. Hey Presto a dropdown menu that will not work with folders/Directories! So frustrating..

Comment: thanks for the edit Palash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this, and it was nothing to do withy the JQuery! Sorry, just my shortcomings in basic html were the issue here. In my li tags I thought they would magically be able to figure out the path themselves or magically know to go back down a level if necessary. lol
I changed these to show like the following:

```
<ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/WebSite/Stuff/DOThis.aspx">menu item 1</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/WebSite/Stuff/DOThat.aspx">menu item 2</a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

This fixed the issue. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

`ResolveClientUrl` creates the URL relative to the current page. Try `ResolveUrl` which creates the URL relative to the root.

Comment: HI Emin, Tried that, but still doubling up on the directory in the path.

Comment: According to the file structure you mention in your question, this should work as expected:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Project/Scripts_Folder/jquery.js") %>"></script>`

When you use the ~ sign, it means it starts from the root and works it down to your defined folder structure.. so for example, the above code (presuming your project is under D:\MyProjects folder) will read D:\MyProjects\Project\Scripts_Folder\jquery.js

Comment: I know in theory it should be, but its as obvious as when I click on the container for the first page it brings it up, but when I click exactly the same container it immediately prefixs the folder directory with the same folder directory again (and the errors of course)

Comment: OK in this case, can you please update your question with some code on how you are trying to accomplish this? especially the binding part. If jquery works fine, the problem is not with including the jquery file. but must be something else..

Comment: I literally just created a new project and created the folder structure that I have already posted. However I am using a 3rd party drop down menu called superfish (free online jquery menu) so there is no extra code.

Answer (score 0):

can do so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts_Folder /jquery.js") %>"></script>
```

Comment: I cant get the URL.Content to work..it says "Url does not exist in current context"

Answer (score 0):

Use Url.Content("~/Scripts_Folder/jquery.js")

Comment: doesn't like the Url.Content does it need a reference for this?

Comment: Is that an MVC project?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="Scripts_Folder/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts_Folder/jcustom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

you might be getting 404 i guess so,

1. check your spaces in `src`
2. try `Url.Content("~/Scripts_Folder/jquery.js")`

Comment: Sorry, the spaces aren't in the actual code.. think I must have just posted the question like that.

Comment: @jbob [MVC View and Javascript URL issue](http://forums.asp.net/t/1246169.aspx?MVC+View+and+Javascript+URL+issue+) - this thread might help you.
& for Url.Content Check your WebpageVersion in config